# I got NullPointerException while i try to run this application for getting data from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

**This is my main activity**
I can't understand what's the wrong going on.while i try to run this,DDMS show NullPointerException.Please help me for find out the error.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnAdd, btnView;
    private TextView txtView;
    private EditText etName;

    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    // private osList oslist;
    private ArrayList<osList> allList;
    private osList olist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setCustomActionBar();

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setCustomActionBar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(
        // com.arifxdroid.listviewdemo.R.color.my_color));
        // actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        // View view = getLayoutInflater()
        // .inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        // actionBar.setCustomView(view, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        // ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        // ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.my_color));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_add) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnAdd:

            String givenName = etName.getText().toString();
            olist = new osList(givenName);
            long inserted = dbHelper.insertOS(olist);
            if (inserted == -1) {
                txtView.setText("Data can't be inserted");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sucessfully added",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.btnView:

            allList = dbHelper.getosList();
            if (allList != null || allList.size() == 0) {
                // txtView.setText("NO list found");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No List found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                for (osList l : allList) {
                    txtView.append("\n" + l.toString());
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

**This is SQLite helper class**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "ListOfOS";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "allOS";
    public static final String ID_FIELD = "_ID";
    public static final String NAME_FIELD = "osName";
    public static final String TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + ID_FIELD + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME_FIELD
            + " TEXT)";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(TABLE_SQL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public long insertOS(osList oslist) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();

        value.put(NAME_FIELD, oslist.getOsName());
        long inserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", value);

        db.close();
        return inserted;
    }

    public ArrayList<osList> getosList() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<osList> all = new ArrayList<osList>();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SQL, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(NAME_FIELD));
                    osList list = new osList(name);
                    all.add(list);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the exception from logcat. I don't wont to read your hole code to find the nullpointer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your Helper class, you havent done it.

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
```